# $f: X \to Y$ is one-one, onto iff $f[A^c] = (f[A])^c$ for any $A \subseteq X$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'll start writing a proof and deliberately make a mistake and try to fix it.

In one direction I have the following:

$y \in (f[A])^c \implies y \not \in f[A] \implies \not \exists x \in A$ s.t. $f(x) = y$ and so $x \in A^c$ meaning $f(x) \in f[A^c]$.

The argument above is incorrect as according to the statement of the problem, I have to invoke "...jectivity" somewhere along the proof which I didn't. I think the mistake is the assertion $x \in A^c$ as $x$ may not even be in $X$. But we can find $x \in X$ with $f(x) = y$ if $f$ is surjective.

So I rewrite the proof as follows:

$y \in (f[A])^c \implies y \not \in f[A] \implies \not \exists x \in A$ s.t. $f(x) = y.$ Because $f$ is surjective $\exists x \in X$ s.t. $f(x) = y$. Since $x \in X$ and $x \not \in A$, it must be that $x \in A^c$ meaning $f(x) \in f[A^c]$.

My questions:

- Is the mistake in the argument pointed out correctly? Or does it lie elsewhere?
- If the mistake was found correctly, is the fix correct as well?
- In the wiki link below, shouldn't the $9$th row under image properties say $f(X \setminus A) \supseteq f(X) \setminus f(A) \iff \text{ ...jective}$? Is it a different situation from the one above?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the mistake is the assertion $x \in A^c$ as $x$ may not even be in $X$.

It's more subtle than that: there is no $x$. The previous statement said that no $x \in A$ fits the bill $f(x) = y$. If you then start talking about an $x$ after that, I have to ask, "which $x$?". What defines $x$? A positive existence statement (such as $\exists x \in A : f(x) = y$) at least gives me a property I'm assuming about $x$, and a set that it belongs to. A non-existence statement gives me nothing.

Also, in order for complements to make sense, there needs to be an assumed universal set. In the case of $A^c$, it is $X$ (i.e. $A^c = X \setminus A$). In the case of $f[A]^c$, it will be $Y$. You can assume, from context, that $A^c$ is a subset of $X$.

> If the mistake was found correctly, is the fix correct as well?

The fix is good. Bear in mind, however, you are only proving $f[A]^c \subseteq f[A^c]$, under the assumption that $f$ is injective and surjective (well, just surjective). You will also need to show $f[A^c] \subseteq f[A]^c$ using injectivity, and that will prove *one direction* of the if and only if proof. You'll then need to show why $f[A]^c = f[A^c]$ for all $A \subseteq X$ must imply injectivity and surjectivity.

> In the wiki link below, shouldn't the $9$th row under image properties say $f(X \setminus A) \supseteq f(X) \setminus f(A) \iff \text{ ...jective}$? Is it a different situation from the one above?

It is slightly different. Remember, $f[A]^c = Y \setminus f(A)$, not just $f(X) \setminus f(A)$. The set $f(X) \setminus f(A)$ is a smaller subset, and thus it's easier to show that is contained in $f(X \setminus A)$, i.e. $f[A^c]$, so fewer assumptions are necessary. Also note that $f(X)$ and $Y$ are the same thing when $f$ is surjective, so you can get the desired result this way too.